# How can I add text to Excel footer using Excel Addin? (Office.js)

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office, office-js

How can I add text to Excel footer using Excel Addin? (Office.js)

The Word case is well documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.section?view=office-js#getfooter-type-

However, there doesn't seem to be a similar set of documentation for footers in Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **preview** API for [Excel.HeaderFooter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.headerfooter?view=office-js) that requires a beta version of Office.js and a custom "Office Insiders" prerelease Office installed in order to interact with Excel headers or footers.

> **Note**
>
> This API is provided as a preview for developers and may change based on feedback that we receive. Do not use this API in a production environment.

[Excel JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets):

> "Please use the latest Office version to try preview APIs (you may need to join the [Office Insider program](https://products.office.com/office-insider))"

---

Comment: No code on a coding support side?